# XML values wont read to string

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

I am having difficulties with my XML code it doesn't seem to saving and when I print it out nothing happens. I am not sure what is wrong because before it would load into my listbox but it would load incorrectly. The code is below and the purpose of my XML reading is the store the values in a list and then get a selected tag and add it to a listbox.

```
String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\XML.xml");
textReader.Read();
XmlNodeType type;

while (textReader.Read())
{
    textReader.MoveToElement();
    type = textReader.NodeType;
    if (type == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {

        if (textReader.Name == "Code")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            code = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "Name")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            name = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "Semester")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            semester = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(semester);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "Prerequisite")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            preReq = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "LectureSlot")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            lSlot = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(lSlot);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "TutorialSlot")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            tSlot = textReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(tSlot);
        }
        if (textReader.Name == "Info")
        {
            textReader.Read();
            info = textReader.Value;
            module.Add(new modules(name, code, semester, tSlot, lSlot, info, preReq));
        }
    }

    foreach (object o in module)
    {
        modules m = (modules)o;
        String hold = m.mName;
        selectionBox.Items.Add(hold);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to know what type of object textReader is.  It obviously isn't a TextReader, but what it IS isn't clear.

Comment: Well, it is a bit tricky to tell without your input XML file. I would recommend running the code in a debugger and look where things goes wrong and understand why.

Comment: I have added the installation of my XML file for your consideration

Comment: I would highly recommend compressing down your example to a pertinent bit. Specifically do you need so many copies of a nearly identical loop. (I could not tell whether they were important so left them intact, since this could be a formatting issue).

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you look for `type == XmlNodeType.Text`, but text nodes does not have any name, no text nodes will match `textReader.Name == "Code"`.

You need to store `textReader.Name` from the last node with `type == XmlNodeType.Element` in a variable and use the stored name when you find the `XmlNodeType.Text` node.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely reason is that in each of your if statements, you are using `textReader.Read()`.  For most `Reader`s this will read the next item, not the current.

As the other answer has said, you need to look at the element for the `Name` and then read for the value.

Consider something like this instead:

```
while (textReader.Read())
    {
        textReader.MoveToElement();
        type = textReader.NodeType;
        if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            textReader.Read();
            switch( textReader.Name )
            {
               case "Code":
                  code = textReader.Value;
                  break;
               case "Name":
                  name = textReader.Value;
                  break;
               //SNIP
               case "Info":
                  info = textReader.Value;
                  module.Add(new modules(name, code, semester, tSlot, lSlot, info, preReq));
                  break;
               default:
                  //Whatever you do here
                  break;
             }
             Console.WriteLine(textReader.Value);
        }
        foreach (object o in module)
        {
            modules m = (modules)o;
            String hold = m.mName;
            selectionBox.Items.Add(hold);
        }


    }
```

This way your XMLTextReader is only reading one node per iteration, and you have a lot fewer if checks - this is the situation a switch case was designed for.